# devtools causes problems in RcppArmadillo packages

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools

The last few days I have been using a lot RcppArmadillo. I have been working on a 3D arrays convolution project. After the initial steep learning curve I managed to create some useful C++ routines using Armadillo. Kudos to Dirk.

Then suddenly RcppArmadillo started doing weird things; I kept getting this message:

```
  Found no calls to: 'R_registerRoutines', 'R_useDynamicSymbols'

It is good practice to register native routines and to disable symbol
search.
```

This happens in Windows 10. In Linux you may receive the same message but it is quickly fixable with `RcppArmadillo::RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` or following the new instructions in `Writing R Extensions - 5.4 Registering native routines`. In Windows **THIS WILL NOT WORK**, though. Why?

To isolate the problem I started with a Virtual Machine (VM) with a fresh R (3.4.1). When you start with the demo that RcppArmadillo builds, it will build the demo without hiccups, no notes, no warning messages. As soon as you install `devtools` the problems with RcppArmadillo begin.

To reproduce this, you can do the following: `(1)` start with a fresh R and install the packages required to run only to build *your-package* with RcppArmadillo (a couple). `(2)` Build your demo package. You will get no errors. `(3)` Download the source of any of these packages that I tested: gckrig, GAS, abcrf, AbsFilterGSEA, Amelia, MAVE, SparseFactorAnalysis, RcppProgress, artfima, geospt. All of them use RcppArmadillo. They should build OK providing you fed them with their dependencies. `(4)` Now, install `devtools`. Immediately after you will start receiving the message:

```
Found no calls to: 'R_registerRoutines', 'R_useDynamicSymbols'
It is good practice to register native routines and to disable symbol
search
```

No mater what I did, I could not get rid off the note. I tried the same packages in Linux and no issue at all. This causes delay because one cannot submit a package to CRAN with that message.

`(5)` Now, if you uninstall `devtools` and dependencies and try again building any RcppArmadillo package; NO MORE message **register native routines**. Beautiful.

I wonder why `devtools` is causing this conflict. How can we get this fixed? I love `devtools` but have to keep it uninstalled if I have to work with RcppArmadillo. Tough choices.

**EDIT**

This is fully reproducible. Here are the steps to reproduce the behavior:

`(1)` start with a fresh R and install the packages required  to build your-package with RcppArmadillo (a couple). Do not install `devtools`.

`(2)` Build your demo package. You will get no *register native routines* errors.

(3) Download the source of any of these packages that I have tested: `gckrig`, `GAS`, `abcrf`, `AbsFilterGSEA`, `Amelia`, `MAVE`, `SparseFactorAnalysis`, `RcppProgress`, `artfima`, `geospt`. All of them use RcppArmadillo. They should build OK providing you fed them with their dependencies.

(4) Now, install `devtools`. Try building again with any of the packages above. Immediately after you will start receiving the message: register native routines.

(5) Now, if you uninstall `devtools` and dependencies and try building again any RcppArmadillo package; no more messages related to *register native routines*.

**EDIT**
This has been tested with three Windows 10 virtual machine instances installing R 3.4.1, Rtools from scratch. In all the tests, building packages with RcppArmadillo finish with the message **register native routines**. If you try to build in Linux -the same package- it will pass with no notes.

Comment: There is nothing reproducible here, and lots of other people use devtools.  You may just be pointing to another old R version.

Comment: Nope. I tested it 3 different virtual machines with R 3.4.1 fresh installations. Otherwise I would not have published it. Have you tried?

Comment: I don't use `devtools` as I (personally) find it obfuscates.  I have been using R much longer than it exists and have my own helper (scripts) but mostly rely on the commands documented and recommended by R Core.  If you have a devtools issue, you know where to complain.  RcppArmadillo itself is fine --- until you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: There were recent changes by R 3.4.* and the need for registration, and the changes made by R and Rcpp. I am almost certain you get tripped up in that -- and I also just uploaded a fix to CRAN which you can find in RcppArmadillo's git repo.  Of course, _none of that has anything to do with devtools_ so maybe your report is on this but just confused. I *still* can't tell as _there is nothing reproducible_.

Comment: I saw that note from the CRAN team. They don't see the problem in Linux either only in Windows. I posted this so people know that the problem can be reproduced and tracked to its source. I can survive without `devtools`. I don't think it is a problem with RcppArmadillo, otherwise the packages would not build. They do. It is just a little bit more salt (devtools) and the stew gets rotten.